# Ajax send image and localstorage value to PHP and receive the same in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My Blow JS send the image to PHP but along with that i trying to send a localstorage value to php and the same to be received in php.

is there a way to send image and a localstorage value to php using ajax and receive the same in php?

PHP:

```
 if(count($_FILES) > 0) {
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'])) {
           $mysl = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root","test");

            $imgData =addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']));
            $imageProperties = getimageSize($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']);

            $sql = "UPDATE output_images SET imageType  ='{$imageProperties['mime']}',imageData= '{$imgData}' WHERE imageId='16'";
            $current_id = mysqli_query($mysl,

$sql) or die("<b>Error:</b> Problem on Image Insert<br/>" . mysqli_error());;
            if(isset($current_id)) {
                echo "done";
            }
        }
        }
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    var storedValue = localStorage.getItem("data");
    $("#uploadForm").on('submit', (function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "upload.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#targetLayer1").html(data);
            },
            error: function () {}
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Is the image upload working? If it is, just add a hidden input in your form and add the localStorage value to it on submit before the ajax.

Comment: @ThanasisGrammatopoulos , thanks for the reply but what about on PHP side how CAN it receive

Comment: You make a POST ajax so for example if your input is <input name="mydata">, you can get the data on php using $_POST["mydata"].
More info here http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: @ThanasisGrammatopoulos, thanks mate worked!!